# How to generate a call graph for a java project

Tags: java, call-graph

Is it possible to generate a global call graph of an application?

Basically I am trying to find the most important class of an application.

I am looking for options for Java.

I have tried Doxy Gen, but it only generates inheritance graphs.

My current script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "digraph G
{"
find $1 -name \*.class |
    sed s/\\.class$// |
    while read x
    do
        javap -v $x | grep " = class" | sed "s%.*// *%\"$x\" -> %" | sed "s/$1\///" | sed "s/-> \(.*\)$/-> \"\1\"/"
    done
echo "}"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a Java call graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982890/how-to-generate-a-java-call-graph)

Comment: "Most important", probably not, but this would probably expose classes with too much functionality, I think.

Comment: @Sean, it may be a duplicate *question* but none of the *answers* there address it.

Comment: @Peter I know, and that's the problem with the "duplicate question" on this site. But it is the policy to close dupes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javap -v` and a bit of perl will get you dependencies between classes. You can make your parser slightly more sophisticated and get dependencies between methods.

Update: or if you have either a *nix or cygwin you can get a list of dependencies as

```
find com/akshor/pjt33/image -name \*.class |
  sed s/\\.class$// |
    while read x
    do
      javap -v $x | grep " = class" | sed "s%.*// *%$x -> %"
    done
```

Add a header and a footer and you can pass  it to dot to render a graph. If you just want to know which classes are used by the most other classes, as your question implies, then

```
find com/akshor/pjt33/image -name \*.class |
  sed s/\\.class$// |
    while read x
    do
      javap -v $x | grep " = class" | sed "s%.*// *%%"
    done |
      sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: I am not sure this can help. And I know close to nothing about Perl. I know its a shame.

Comment: @Tiago, you can read input and apply regular expression in Java too, it's just rather more verbose.

Comment: I'll give this a try. I am guessing that this command will look for files in `com/akshor/pjt33/image` with the `*.class`extension, but shouldn't it be `*.java`? I was under the impression the `javap` command would read java files and not class files.

Comment: Never mind. I am almost done with this, I am tweaking your bash script to my needs.

Comment: @Peter: I am getting some weird symbols like [Z and [B. I have added the current version of the script I am building on my question.

Comment: @Tiago, oops, I should have removed that path: I was just using it for testing. [Z means boolean[], [B means byte[]. javap is the disassembler: it reads class files (and insists on the class name rather than the file name) and emits, depending on the options you give it, anything from a list of public members to the entire constant pool and bytecode in a form which just needs a bit of tweaking to compile it with jasmin.

Answer (score 1):

For advanced code analysis you might wanna have a look at http://www.moosetechnology.org/

Cheers
Thomas

(**edit:** moved down here by general request, See: [How to generate a Java call graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982890/how-to-generate-a-java-call-graph))

Comment: LOL... you beat me to the punch (+1)

Comment: I don't think you understand what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I have seen that question, but it does not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Tiago and what about Moose? I used this tool to analyse projects at work.